# Proof that plane has small inductive dimension 2?

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

By definition, the *small inductive dimension* $\operatorname{ind}(\emptyset) = -1$ and, recursively, the small inductive dimension $\operatorname{ind}(X)$ of a nonempty topological space $X$ is the least integer $n \geq 0$ such that each point $x$ has a local base (i.e., a neighborhood base) of open sets $V$ such that $\operatorname{ind}(\operatorname{\partial} V) \leq n - 1$, where $\operatorname{\partial} V$ denotes the boundary of $V$.

(Some versions of the definition require that each neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contain such a $V$ with $\operatorname{cls} V \subset U$. However, that requirement here is redundant since the spaces involved are regular.)

That $\operatorname{ind}(\mathbb{R}) = 1$ is easy to see: $\mathbb{R} \neq \emptyset$; and each point in $\mathbb{R}$ has arbitrarily small neighborhoods of the form $V = (a, b)$, and $\partial\,V$ is the two-point discrete space $\{a, b\}$, which is 0-dimensional.

But what about $\mathbb{R}^2$:
**is there an *elementary* proof that $\operatorname{ind} (\mathbb{R}^2) = 2$?**

Evidently $\operatorname{ind}(\mathbb{R}^2) \leq 2$, since each point has arbitrarily small neighborhoods that are open disks, and the boundary of such a disk has small inductive dimension $1$. Moreover, $\operatorname{ind}(\mathbb{R}^2) \neq 0$, since the plane is connected; and of course $\operatorname{ind}(\mathbb{R}^2) \neq -1$.

So the thing that remains to prove is that $\operatorname{ind} (\mathbb{R}^2) \neq 1$.

I know there are not-so-elementary proofs that  $\operatorname{ind} (\mathbb{R}^n) = n$, but I'm looking for an elementary proof just in the case $n = 2$.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Thank you for the edit.  This is a slightly different phrasing than I am familiar with.  Let me think for a bit, but I *think* I might have a convincing "elementary" argument.

Answer (score 1):

In my book

> *Edgar, Gerald A.*, Measure, topology, and fractal geometry, Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics. New York etc.: Springer-Verlag. ix, 230 p. DM 58.00/hbk (1990). [ZBL0727.28003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0727.28003).

I included what I considered to be the most elementary proof of this fact, Theorem 3.3.4.  [It's about 4 pages.] This is done first talking about degree (mod 2) of a map from the circle to itself; then Brouwer's fixed point theorem for the disk; then the topological dimension of the plane.

In the first edition of the book, where I do inductive dimension first, this is done with inductive dimension.  In the second edition of the book I switched to the more common arrangement, doing covering dimension first, so this is done with covering dimension.

Comment: I am interested in the case of small inductive dimension, and to get at the proof directly, *without* using the theorem about equality of covering dimension and small inductive dimension for separable metrizable spaces. Alas, I own, and have access, only to the 2nd edition.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that for every bounded open set $V$ on the plane, its boundary $\partial V$ has a connected subset that has more than one point. Let $V_1$ be a connected component of $V$. Then $K=\overline{V_1}$ is compact and connected. Its complement $K^c$ contains exactly one unbounded connected  component $D$. For this domain $D$, its complement $D^c$ consists of $K$ together with the bounded domains in $K^c$, so it is elementary to verify that $D^c$ is connected. Thus the union $D\cup \{\infty\}$ is simply connected on the Riemann sphere, see [2]. Therefore the boundary
$\partial D$ is connected, see e.g. [1]. Certainly $\partial D$ contains more than 1 point. But $\partial D \subset \partial K =\partial V_1 \subset \partial V$.

[1] [Is it true that a boundary of a simply connected and bounded set is connected in $\mathbb{C}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503230/is-it-true-that-a-boundary-of-a-simply-connected-and-bounded-set-is-connected-in)

[2] [Complement is connected iff Connected components are Simply Connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330479/complement-is-connected-iff-connected-components-are-simply-connected?rq=1)

Comment: You state that both $D$ and $D\cup\{\infty\}$ are simply connected but I guess you mean only the latter, right?  Still this is not entirely clear to me.  How would you prove it?

Comment: Right, only $D \cup\{\infty\}$ is simply connected. I will add some more detail to the answer.

Comment: Robert Israel's answer in [2] assumes that a simple (Jordan) curve in the plane is homotopic to a constant within the bounded region it determines.  Although this sounds reasonable, I don't know how to prove it in detail!  Do you?

Comment: Another fact used by Robert in [2] making me a bit unsure is that a non-simply connected space admits a **simple** curve not homotopically trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is supposed to be a complement to the answer offered by Yuval Perez, with the following observations:

1. I am not convinced of the proof given in the  link
   [Is it true that a boundary of a simply connected and bounded set is connected in $\mathbb{C}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503230/is-it-true-that-a-boundary-of-a-simply-connected-and-bounded-set-is-connected-in),
   so my answer essentially attempts to fix the part of Yuval's answer that uses that link.
2. As I mentioned in a comment below Yuval's answer, I am not entirely comfortable with the claim that the set denoted $D$ in Yuval's answer is indeed simply connected (after $\infty $ is added to
   it).  Unfortunately I have no easy fix for this, hence my own answer is dependent on this point.

This said,  as noted by Yuval, it suffices to prove the following:

**Lemma**.  If $U$ is a nonempty, open,  bounded, simply connected subset of ${\mathbb R}^2$,  then the
boundary $\partial U$ is connected.

*Proof*.
Identifying ${\mathbb R}^2$ with the complex plane,  and using the Riemann mapping theorem, there is a bi-holomorphic
map $f$ from the open unit disk $\mathbb D$ onto $U$.

For each real number $r$ in the interval $(0,1)$, consider the subset of $U$ defined by
$$
  C_r= \{f(z): |z|=r\}.
  $$

[image: Diagram]

Roughly speaking, we will prove that the $C_r$ *converge* to $\partial U$, and since each $C_r$ is connected, so
will be $\partial U$.  The details are as follows:

Fixing $\varepsilon >0$, denote by $V_\varepsilon $ the open set
$$
  V_\varepsilon :=\{x\in  U: \text{dist}(x, \partial U)<\varepsilon \}. \tag {1}
  $$
We then claim that
there is some $r_0\in (0,1)$ such that, for every $r$ in $(0,1)$, with $r>r_0$, one
has that
$$
  C_r\subseteq V_\varepsilon .
  $$

To prove the claim, observe that
$$
  K_\varepsilon := U\setminus V_\varepsilon  = \{x\in  U: \text{dist}(x, \partial U)\geq \varepsilon \}
  $$
is  a compact set (Reason: every sequence in $K_\varepsilon $ has a sub-sequence wich converges in  $\bar U$,
say with limit  $x$, because $\bar U$ is compact.  By continuity $\text{dist}(x, \partial U)\geq \varepsilon $, so $x$ is not in
$\partial U$, meaning that $x\in  U$).

The collection of sets
$$
  D_r:= \{f(z) : |z|<r\},
  $$
for $r$ ranging in $(0,1)$,
clearly forms  a cover for $U$, and in particular also for  $K_\varepsilon $.  Since the $D_r$  are increasing, by compactness there is
some $r_0$ such that $K_\varepsilon \subseteq D_{r_0}$,  and hence also $K_\varepsilon \subseteq D_r$, for every $r\geq r_0$.  It follows that
$$
  C_r \subseteq U\setminus D_r \subseteq  U \setminus K_\varepsilon  = V_\varepsilon ,
  $$
as desired.

Assuming by contradiction that $\partial U$ is disconnected, write $\partial U=B_1\sqcup B_2$, where $B_1$ and $B_2$ are
nonempty,
closed sets,  "$\sqcup$" standing for disjoint union.

[image: Diagram2]

Since both $B_1$ and $B_2$ are closed and bounded,  they are compact and hence their distance is strictly positive.  In symbols
$$
  d:= \inf\{|x-y|: x\in B_1, \ y\in  B_2\} >0.
  $$
We then consider, for every $i=1,2$, the open set
$$
  W_i=\{x\in  U: \text{dist}(x, B_i) < d/2\}.
  $$
Evidently $W_1\cap W_2=\emptyset$, while $W_1\cup W_2=V_{d/2}$ (as defined in (1)).

Taking  $r_0$, as above, for the choice of $\varepsilon =d/2$, we conclude that for every $r$ in the interval $(r_0, 1)$, one has that
$$
  C_r\subseteq W_1\cup W_2.
  $$
Observing that $C_r$ is connected, we deduce that either $C_r\subseteq W_1$, or $C_r\subseteq W_2$.

However,  it is a simple matter to show that, for every $i$, the set
$$
  J_i:= \{r\in  (r_0, 1): C_r\subseteq W_i\}
  $$
is open.  Since $(r_0, 1)= J_1\sqcup J_2$, we have by connectedness that either $J_1$ or $J_2$ coincides with
$(r_0,1)$.  We then suppose, without loss of generality that $J_1=(r_0, 1)$, which is to say that
$$
  C_r\subseteq W_1,\quad \forall r\in  (r_0,1).\tag {2}
  $$

Pick some point $x$ in $B_2$, and let $\{x_n\}_n$ be a sequence in $U$, converging to $x$.  Assuming, as we may,  that
$|x_n-x|<d/2$, we  necessarily have that  $x_n\in  W_2$.

Write $x_n=f(z_n)$, where $z_n$ lies in the open unit disk $\mathbb D$.  By passing to a subsequence, we may assume that
$\{z_n\}_n$ converges to some point  $z\in  \bar {\mathbb D}$.  Clearly $z$ cannot lie in ${\mathbb D}$, because otherwise
$$
  x = \lim_n x_n =  \lim_n f(z_n)  = f(z) \in  U,
  $$
but we know that $x\in  B_2\subseteq \partial U$.

It follows that $|z|=1$, so $\lim_n|z_n|=1$, and hence there is some $n_0$ such that $n\geq n_0$ entails $|z_n|>r_0$.
This implies that, for $n\geq n_0$,
$$
  x_n=f(z_n) \in  C_{|z_n|} \subseteq  W_1,
  $$
by (2),  contradicting the fact that $x_n$ lies in $W_2$. QED

Comment: I would hardly call the preceding an "elementary" proof, using as it does the Riemann mapping theorem!

Comment: How about the Jordan curve Theorem which is also implicitly used here and in the other answers?  Unfortunately some facts that look elementary often require a bit of work!

Comment: It seems not wholly unreasonable to allow the Jordan curve theorem in an "elementary" proof, although something more basic such as the Brouwer fixed-point theorem in dimension 2 would be preferable.